# How do I remove a site from IIS7 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iis-7

I've been searching the Internet for a way to remove a site from IIS7 using JavaScript. I've found, and used, a lot of examples on how to create a site and applications using JavaScript but not a single example on how to delete a site!

I figured that since the .Net System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection-class has a BaseRemoveAt()-method, then there should be a corresponding method in JavaScript, but I have not found any.

Does anyone know how to remove a site from IIS7 using JavaScript?

Please help!

/Petteri

Comment: How do you add a site to IIS using Javascript? I have never seen that done.

Comment: I assume this question is about JScript in a WSH environment. JavaScript is **not** limited to web browsers.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525808.aspx has some information about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525808.aspx (although not, I suspect, enough to answer this question, which is why I provide it as a comment for nay-sayers rather than an answer).

Comment: Here is where I have found out how to create a site using JavaScript: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites.

No joke!

Comment: Since it is possible to create a site using JavaScript (see http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites), it should be possible to delete one too, or am I asking for too much?

Comment: I think you are just asking something that is quite obscure. Give it time, someone might turn up who knows about it. (It's a shame that "Is this a joke?" seems to be have upvoted twice since explanations about why it isn't a joke have been posted :( ).

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault.  Close it, people.

Comment: Josh: When I posted this question on ServerFault, it was tagged belongs-on-stackoverflow...

Comment: That's the trouble with "Programatically performing sysad tasks" — you get overlap. It's a shame that a question can't appear on both sites (that's a single question, not a copy).

Answer (score 0):

The method you were looking for is called `DeleteElement`. See an example of its usage [here](http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/how-to-add-lt-clear-gt-or-lt-remove-gt-elements-through-scripting).